# How many RTSP packets are required to send the smallest, fully visible, valid image to a remote network?

Tags: image-processing, network-protocols, rtsp, packet

If the number of packets is 1, what is the largest size image (more than likely GIF) a single rtp packet can send?

Any adjustments to the protocol are fine just as long as it works and the image is valid and visible to the human eye. Also, if one packet is not enough have many are necessary?

Comment: RTSP is kind of stream(s) initiation protocol, so you have to send multiple TCP packets before you'll be able to send a single RTP packet over UDP or TCP. You can also control size of your tcp or udp packets and can use jumbo packets. But, usually, tcp or udp packet size is around 1500 bytes. RFC 2435 (RTP payload for JPEG images) may help you to check if you can send single jpeg image ini one packet.